# Can you install / activate the multisite when the install is in a subfolder?

Tags: multisite, domain

I have *primarydomain.com* and an *addondomain.com*

*addondomain.com* points to *primarydomain.com/addondomain*

I have installed 2 seperate installs of wordpress on *primarydomain.com* and *primarydomain.com/addondomain*

Can I activate multisite on *primarydomain.com/addondomain* as *addondomain.com*?

My reason for this is these are two separate sites with two separate functions, so I wanted to use separate databases. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as long as you use addondomain.com to access the Multisite.

Comment: So all I need to do is activate the multisite on addondomain.com, and it'll work? Simply uploading a backed-up multisite into won't do?

Comment: Yes, if you activate the multisite on addondomain.com, it will work.

Comment: Uploading a backed-up multisite will work too. You will just need to replace all the occurrences of the old domain name by the new one in the database and wp-config.php

Comment: Thank you. One last thing: the backup I am using has the subsites in _subdomain.addondomain.com_ but right now it doesn't work anymore. Do I need to do something else for this to work? Or I'll have to settle with _addondomain.com/formersubdomain_ ?

Comment: @Yukihana, see @andrea_r reply.

Answer (score 0):

For the subdomains, if you have access to Apache you can enable the wildcards for the add-on domain.

if not, and you only have cpanel, you're stuck. on most shared hosts, the wildcard record goes to the primary domain only.